# How to rename a column in Spark dataframe while using explode function

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to use explode array function in Pyspark and below is the code -

```
 df_map_transformation.select(col("_name") , explode(arrays_zip(col("instances.Instance._name"), col("instances.Instance._id") ))).select(col("_name"), col("col.*")).printSchema()
```

Output -

```
root
 |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1: string (nullable = true)
```

When I am trying to select "_name" column I am able to do so like -

```
df_map_transformation.select(col("_name") , explode(arrays_zip(col("instances.Instance._name"), col("instances.Instance._id") ))).select(col("_name"), col("col.*")).select(col("_name")).show(50,False)
```

But the same is not working while trying to access "0" or "1" column - 
Error -

```
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1614.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: _gen_alias_696#696
```

Is there any way to rename column "0" and "1" or extract them via select in dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cast to `col` column to `struct<cola:string,colb:string>`. You can choose your own column names inside struct, for example I have taken `cola & colb`

Check below code.

```
df_map_transformation.select(col("_name") , explode(arrays_zip(col("instances.Instance._name"), col("instances.Instance._id") ))).select(col("_name"), col("col").cast("struct<cola:string,colb:string>")).select(col("_name"),col("col.cola"),col("col.colb")).printSchema()

root
 |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cola: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colb: string (nullable = true)
```

Also you can use `withColumnRenamed`

```
df_map_transformation.select(col("_name") ,explode(
 arrays_zip(
  col("instances.Instance._name"), 
  col("instances.Instance._id") )
 )
).select(col("_name"), col("col.*"))
.withColumnRenamed("0","cola")
.withColumnRenamed("1","colb")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode('col_name').alias('new_name')`

Answer (score 1):

```
 df = (df_map_transformation
        .select(
            col("_name"), 
            explode(arrays_zip(
                col("instances.Instance._name"), 
                col("instances.Instance._id") 
            )
              .alias('name','id')  # <-- alias can take multiple names
         )
      )
```

here's what it looks like in my notebook:

[image]